# HTTP Delete Request to MYSQL with user ID variable

Tags: php, android, mysql, httprequest

Hi I am trying to delete a record from a table within MYSQL database with a where clause. 
this is what I have so far but its not working, and im not sure how to go about it. Is there a way to make this work? I have included my delete method and php file code.

my URL -

```
 deleteCompletedGoal=("http://10.0.2.2/deleteCompletedGoalAddress.php?user_goal_id="+completed_goalID);
```

my code -

```
 private void deleteNonActiveGoal(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(deleteCompletedGoal);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "DELETE");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ops, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_goal_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(completed_goalID, "UTF-8") + "&&";

            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            ops.close();

            InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "ISO-8859-1"));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            reader.close();
            ips.close();
            http.disconnect();

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        }

    }
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

$completed_goalID=$_POST["user_goal_id"];


$mysql_qry = "DELETE from user_goals WHERE user_goal_id ='$completed_goalID'";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
echo "delete successful";
}
else{
echo "delete failed";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Pretty sure this is a case for "undefined index". You're using a GET method for URL retrieval but POST the index.

Comment: @JayBlanchard They're not using mysql_ ;-)

Comment: Not enough coffee yet @FunkFortyNiner ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Too bad I couldn't ship you another via the *"Beam me up Scotty"* mosheen ;-))

Comment: LOL - no doubt! @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: I have changed the http Request method to Get and same in the php file but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending the variable in the query string you would use GET instead of POST. Change:

```
 $completed_goalID=$_POST["user_goal_id"];
```

to

```
$completed_goalID=$_GET["user_goal_id"];
```

**WARNING**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @KasiaKaplińska are you getting any errors in your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET for catch variable from url like:

```
$completed_goalID=$_GET["user_goal_id"];
```

Change query for prevent sql attack ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) like:

```
 <?php
    require "connection.php";

    $completed_goalID=$_POST["user_goal_id"];


    $mysql_qry = $conn->prepare("DELETE from user_goals WHERE user_goal_id=?");
    $mysql_qry->bind_param('i',$completed_goalID);
    if($mysql_qry->execute() === TRUE){

    echo "delete successful";
    }
    else{
    echo "delete failed";
    }
   $mysql_qry->close();
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```